# how to solve the following mordell equation:$ y^2 = x^3 - 3$

Tags: number-theory

i just started solving mordell's equations and get a little bit stuck. For example:

$ y^2 = x^3 - 3$.

I know that $x$ must be odd, for if $x$ is even $y^2 \equiv 5 \pmod{8}$. So $x \equiv \{1,3\} \pmod{4}$. Now note the following if we add 4 at both sides:

$y^2 + 4 = (x+1)(x^2 -x +1)$. The right hand side is the same as $(x-1)^2 + x$

I now know $(x^2 -x +1)$ is divisible by a prime divisor $3 \pmod{4}$ if $x \equiv 3 \pmod {4}$ and divisible by $1 \pmod{4}$ if $x \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$.

So we get $y^2 + 4 \equiv 0\pmod{p}$, which is solvable if $\left(\frac{-2}{p}\right)$ = 1. (I don't think this step is valid). this is only true if the following occurs:

$p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ and $p \equiv +- 1\pmod{8}$.

or

$p \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$ and $p \equiv +- 3\pmod{8}$.

so $p \equiv \{1,3\}\pmod{8}$

but $y^2 + 4$ is either $4 \pmod{8}$ or $5 \pmod {8}$, so there are no solutions?

Am i solving this the correct way or is there a shorter path?

Kees

Comment: $y^2+4\equiv 0\pmod{p}$ is solvable iff either $p=2$ or $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think this is the best way. Keith Conrad has answered this with many examples in his article [Examples of Mordell's equation](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAAahUKEwiS3uPqpYPJAhXClnIKHS2rC7Q&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.uconn.edu%2F~kconrad%2Fblurbs%2Fgradnumthy%2Fmordelleqn1.pdf&usg=AFQjCNExJsQ8bikneg2KeVVzvOH_vwlctQ&bvm=bv.106923889,d.bGg); e.g., compare with Theorem $2.2$ and $2.3$, which is very similar, for $y^2=x^3-5$ and $y^2=x^3-6$.

Comment: i think i made a mistake, can it be tht this equation has solutions?

Comment: There are no integer solutions, see [here](http://oeis.org/A081121). So $y^2=x^3+n$ has no integer solutions for $n=-3,-5, -6, -9, -10, -12, -14, -16, -17$ and so on.

Comment: i get that, but i think my calculation is wrong, because y^2 + 4 \equiv 0 \pmod{4} does not imply that $\left( \frac{-2}{p} \right) = 1$

Comment: $-4$ is a square if $-1$ is a square and $p>2$.

Comment: hmmmmm, can you explain that more detailed, i don't see why that is true

Comment: hmmmmm, you really should try this. I think we have to stop here, see below.

Comment: You can't claim "it's the best way", because it's not a correct solution.

Comment: @user236182 I meant, this "method" is the best way in this case; a correct solution is well-known, and the OP should try to find it himself.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is flawed, so here's a complete solution: As you said, $x$ is odd, because if $x$ were even, then $y^2\equiv -3\pmod{8}$, which is not a quadratic residue. Then $y=2k$ is even.

$4(k^2+1)=(x+1)\left(x^2-x+1\right)$.

$x^2-x+1$ is always odd. Let $p$ be a prime divisor of $x^2-x+1$. Then $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, because if $p\equiv 3\pmod{4}$, then $k^2\equiv -1\pmod{p}$, contradiction (by [Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#.E2.88.921_and_the_first_supplement)). Therefore $x^2-x+1\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, so $4\mid x(x-1)$, so $4\mid x-1$, i.e. $x\equiv 1\pmod{4}$. But then $x+1\equiv 2\pmod{4}$, contradiction, because this implies $4\nmid (x+1)\left(x^2-x+1\right)$ (while $4$ divides the LHS). No solutions exist.